# discord.py 2.0: unable to get interaction response from a matrix of buttons

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

i'm trying to get individual outputs from the bot for a matrix of buttons. I made a function which creates the matrix, then i haven't found a way to interact with individual buttons.

thanks in advance :)

```py
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    from discord.ui import Button, View

    class MyButton(View):
    def __init__(self, label_list): #label_list is a list of string
        super().__init__()
        for i in range(len(label_list)):
            self.add_item(Button(label=label_list[i], custom_id=str(i)))
    
    #buttons callback?

    @bot.command()
    async def arraybutton(ctx, label_list):
        button = MyButton(label_list)
        await ctx.send("select:", view=button)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting aside that I think that your `label_list` is a string and I don't really get how that works, I'm pretty sure the button interactions are supposed be done by subclassing Button and redefining their callback method.

```py
class MyButton(discord.ui.Button):
    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        self.style = discord.ButtonStyle.red
        self.label = self.label + " was pressed by " + interaction.user.name
        await interaction.response.edit_message(view=self)
        

class MyView(View):
    def __init__(self, label_list):  # label_list is a list of string
        super().__init__()
        for i in range(len(label_list)):
            self.add_item(MyButton(label=label_list[i], custom_id=str(i)))
```

I've been using the [pycord documentation for Button/View UI stuff](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=view#bot-ui-kit) and it seems to be more-or-less the same code as discord.py, but I can't find discord.py ui documentation.